# Sorting alfresco search by node path

Tags: alfresco

Is it possible to sort search results from alfresco by the path of the node?
I know there is the PATH field, but that is a multi-valued attribute which SOLR is unable to sort on.

I know it would be possible to capture the path of the node in a custom attribute and sort on that, however there are many scenarios this would be unable to capture (e.g. if a parent folder name is changed for a locked node) so would prefer an alfresco field if it is possible

This is on alfresco version 6.1 with SOLR 6

Comment: I think you're out of lock. What are you trying to do, why do you need this?

Comment: I'm trying to sort by the path of the node? It is more useful than just sorting by the name in most scenarios. 
I had hoped there was an inbuilt way to do this, but if not I will just have to store the path in a custom property and index on that